# Using grep and * to get the exact file name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have following heapdump files

```
AppSrv01]# ls -ltr *heapdump*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3436
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3435
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3434
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3433
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3432
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3431
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 17:03 heapdump.dfsdf
```

now if I use

```
ls -ltr| grep heapdump*
```

I get following output

```
AppSrv01]# ls -ltr |grep heapdump*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Sep 13 17:03 heapdump.dfsdf
```

But I use

```
ls -ltr |grep *heapdump*
```

I get no output. Could anybody help where is my mistake and how to search the heapdump files.

My expected output is

```
ls -ltr | grep *heapdump*
```

should give me

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3436
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3435
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3434
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3433
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3432
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 16:44 hbsbdheapdump.3431
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 17:03 heapdump.dfsdf
```

due to some reason I could not use

```
ls -ltr *heapdump*
```

Comment: The `*` is expanded by the shell into a single file in the first instance and multiple files in the second, In the second instance you will be searching for the first file matched inside all the other files. Quoting `*headdump*` will likely give you desired behaviour.

Comment: What exactly is the output you're looking for? Could you [edit] your question to make it more clear?

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing glob patterns with regular expressions, which is what `grep` uses.

The correct way to print a list of files containing the word `heapdump` is like this:

```
printf '%s\n' *heapdump*
```

Here, `*heapdump*` is glob-expanded by the shell to match anything followed by "heapdump" followed by anything else. All the files that match the pattern are passed to `printf`, which prints each one followed by a newline.

If you want to filter the output of `ls -ltr`, then you can use:

```
ls -ltr *heapdump*
```

The same list of files will be passed to `ls`, which will print information about them.

Bear in mind that [it is **not** recommended to attempt to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your reply, could you share some contents/ links explaining why ls output should not be parsed, as I do it usually and will have to correct my habits if its wrong.

Comment: My answer already contains a link - searching "parse ls" will also yield plenty of results.

Comment: Thanks allot 

    printf '%s\n' *heapdump*
has made my life much easy

Comment: No problem - of course this method will fail if your file names contain newline characters (which is technically a possibility).